# Как изменить значение элемента в окне WPF

Tags: wpf, чат, richtextbox

Пишу чат на базе WPF. Пытался обратиться к элементу через Dispatcher.Invoke, безрезультатно. В WindowsForms при введении делегата в родной поток элемента методом Invoke(MethodInvoker) всё работало прекрасно, а вот тут... Что то не так. Долго искал информацию на зарубежных форумах, в том числе и на MDSN, но снова ничего. Каким образом изменить текст в RichTextBox в тот момент, когда окно скрыто? 
Постскриптум, я новичок, многого не знаю, но постепенно набираюсь опыта. Вот уже часа 2 - 3 думаю над этой тонкостью.

Comment: Не уверен, что правильно понял вопрос, изменять значение вы можете через привязку. Зачем вам менять текст когда окно скрыто?

Comment: Я уже понял в чем была проблема, думаю, что вопрос решен.

Comment: В таком случае напишите ответ ;)

Comment: в том случае, если ответ на вопрос остался неясным или есть еще какие-то проблемы с WPF, вы можете спросить меня в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50036/f) буду рад помочь, если это будет в моих силах :)